# Small program that uses pointers to sum integers

Tags: c, pointers, sum, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I need to create a program which calculates the cumulative sum of a dynamically allocated vector and **the vector should be filled with random values** (not values from stdin) ​​using `only pointers`. I couldn't think of a version that uses only pointers (i'm kinda new to this matter).

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n, sum = 0;
    int *a;

    printf("Define size of your array A \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    a = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    printf("Add the elements: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", a + i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + *(a + i);
    }

    printf("Sum of all the elements in the array = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If by 'script' you mean just a function definition then you shouldn't need to use static variables at all. Accept a pointer which is the start of the vector; you'll either then need some convention for the end of the vector e.g. the value zero, or also accept another argument which is the length of the vector or a pointer to the end of the vector, and then just iterate through the vector adding up the values. I guess the idea is that you don't use an int as your loop variable but increase the pointer as you go.

Comment: we dont do task for you, try to make it with static variables and someone may rework it for you with pointers

Comment: There are no static variables in your code.

Comment: @bereal need to use only pointers, nothing else

Comment: its not static variable when u write sum=0 i guess as @bereal said when u increment it in code, but if u have problem with that, u can use *sum to assign values

Comment: I don't think there's a sane way to do it without pointers, because you need int variables to store array length and loop index. Except, maybe, some hackish hacks that no one will use in real life.

Comment: btw its working? you store variables as (a+i), so increment by 1, but u have integer array, so u dont need 4bits for every number?

Comment: @bereal yeah, that's usually our task to do... something you wouldn't find exactly on a google search that no one's gonna ever use

Comment: @efysis the program itself works out well at the current state, yet what should i do about int i and n considering (let's say) we change and he accepts sum  as *sum ?

Comment: The term "script" is not used in the context of the C language.

Comment: Don't use `*(a + i)` but the more idiomatic `a[i]`. Also within `scanf` don't use `a + i` but `&a[i]`. It's the same thing, but nobody writes `*(a + i)`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misunderstand the requirement "using only pointers"? This requirement sounds rather stupid to me.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i didn't, trust me.. it is at stupid as it sounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not something that much more complicated, instead of declaring `int` variables you need to declare `int` pointers and then allocate memory for them.

Something like:

[**Running sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/Hk000igvI)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int *n = malloc(sizeof(int)); //memory allocation for needed variables
    int *sum = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *a;

    srand(time(NULL)); //seed

    printf("Define size of your array A \n");
    scanf("%d", n);

    if (*n < 1) {                  //size must be > 0
        puts("Invalid size");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Generating random values... \n");
    a = malloc(sizeof(int) * *n); //allocating array of ints
    *sum = 0;                     //reseting sum

    while ((*n)--) {
        a[*n] = rand() % 1000 + 1; // adding random numbers to the array from 1 to 1000
        //scanf("%d", &a[*n]); //storing values in the array from stdin
        *sum += a[*n];       // adding values in sum
    }

    printf("Sum of all the elements in the array = %d\n", *sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Added random number generation instead of stdin values

Comment: need to fill the vector with random values, not to have them from standard input

Comment: @JonBjatBun, I changed my answer to accomodate your spec.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this instead of static variable

```
int main(){
    void *memory = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *ptr = (int *)memory;
    *ptr = 20;
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    free(memory);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good idea to satisfy a stupid requirement (using only pointers).